# How to list a directory with a large number of files in php?

Tags: php, file

I knew this will happens some day... So I have a php routine to list files in a directory, get properties and subdirectories and return the http call with a nice json string with all information. In my localhost I use it to list all files in a directory and subdirectories recursively, so I will have the total amount of bytes, etc.. This is the part of the code that actually list the files:

```
        (...)
        $this->Lista = array();
        $this->SubDirs = array();
        $ldPont  = opendir($dir);
        if(!$ldPont){
            $this->erro = 'perms';
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            $this->tamanho = 0;
            $this->tamanhoTotal = 0;
            while(FALSE !== ($ldNome = readdir($ldPont))) {
                if(substr($ldNome, 0, 1)!="." && substr($ldNome, 0, 2)!=".."){
                    //echo('<p>'.$ldNome.'</p>');
                    if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ldNome)){
                        $this->SubDirs[] = $this->elementoDoArquivo($dir.'/'.$ldNome);
                    } else {
                        $path = $dir.'/'.$ldNome;
                        $this->tamanhoTotal += filesize($path);
                        $ldBase = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                        $ldExt = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        $ldExt = strtolower($ldExt);
                        if(is_array($Exts) && count($Exts)>0){
                            $ldTeste = in_array($ldExt, $Exts);
                        } else {
                            $ldTeste = TRUE;
                        }
                        if($ldTeste) {
                            $Arq = $this->elementoDoArquivo($path);
                            if($Arq["Metadados"]) $this->comMetadados = TRUE;
                            $this->Props[$Arq["Prop"]["name"]] = $Arq["Prop"];
                            $this->tamanho += $Arq["bytes"];
                            $this->Lista[] = $Arq;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // Saída de uma leitura ok
            closedir($ldPont);
            uasort($this->Lista, $sort_func[$ord]); //$sort_func[$this->ordem]);
            if($ord_r) $this->Lista = array_reverse($this->Lista);
            $this->Lista = array_values($this->Lista);
            return $this->Lista;
        }
```

It's a class. Listing the directory performs a lot of tasks and eventually it will timeout in the remote server with a large number of files, depending on the availability of the server (it's shared hosting). I think I need to deal with this in a different way, don't know how. Any suggestions?

EDIT: I workaround the problem with a lighter code that uses glob and don't look for so much details of each file. With a few trials I could get the needed result. But the problem still persists... The code is part of a larger library, here is the part I used:

```
    case "list":
        if(!$usrRead){
            $Res->erro = "perms";
            $Res->msg = "Usuário sem permissões para esse diretório.";
            $Res->descr = $UsrPerms;
            break;
        }
        $Arqs = array();
        $Dirs = array();
        if(!is_dir($dirTeste)){
            $Res->erro = "diretório";
            $Res->msg = "O diretório não existe.";
        } else {
            $Args = explode(",",$nome);
            foreach($Args as $arg){
                if($arg=="") $arg = "*.*";
                $List = glob($dir.$arg);
                foreach($List as $path){
                    if(is_file($path)) {
                        $Arq = array(
                            "nome"=>basename($path), 
                            "datac"=>filectime($path), 
                            "datam"=>filemtime($path), 
                            "bytes"=>filesize($path));
                        if($MetaCampos){
                            $path_meta = nomearqMeta($path);
                            if($path_meta) {
                                $Meta = json_decode(file_get_contents($path_meta));
                                if($Meta) {
                                    foreach($MetaCampos as $campo){
                                        $Arq[$campo] = $Meta->$campo;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        $Arqs[] = $Arq;
                    }
                    //if(is_dir($path)) $Dirs[] = $path;
                }
            }
            if(count($Args)==1) {
                $Dirs = glob($dir."*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
                $Dirs = array_map(function($d) { return $d."/"; }, $Dirs);
            }
            $Res->arqs = $Arqs;
            $Res->subdirs = $Dirs;
            $Res->erro = "OK";
            $Res->msg = "";
        }
        $Res->descr = "op:list,dir:".$dir.",nome:".$nome.",metaCampos:".$metaCampos;
        break;
```

Comment: fs operations tend to be slow, especially if its a shared host, work around it by writing a script which puts all the info you need about the files in a db, then either watch the db for changes and update the fs or the other way, then simply use pagination in showing the result. also SUM'ing a column is much more efficient than counting bytes

Comment: The idea is interesting, but don't know exactly how to execute, since will demand scan files anyway. I might create a script to run in every hour, but might crash anyway. I have a mailer script that divide the sending task in blocks of 50 emails to prevent crash, but I have the list, witch I don't have in the files case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running on Linux, I would suggest to execute a recursive dir listing via PHP's shell_exec (Or exec) and output the result in a text file (see code example below). Then, just file_get_contents() with PHP

```
<?php

$execListFile = shell_exec('ls -R /your/dir/path/here > mylistofFiles.txt');

$myFiles = file_get_contents('mylistofFiles.txt');
```

PS: This code is untested, but you get the idea.

References
[PHP.net shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php)
[Linux ls command](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/ls.html)

PS: Window's equivalent of ls -R is dir /s

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I am wondering if execution of a Linux command by shell will be really different from using a PHP command, both will hang until the OS return the data required. If the OS take to long, PHP will reach timeout anyway. Is it possible to divide the task in small answers, small packages, like downloading a file that never timeout?

Comment: Check set_time_limit(0); to prevent timeouts

http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

How often do you need to list your files? Maybe you can use the PHP's directory iterator? See below...

$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("/your/directory/here/");

foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file) {

}

ref: http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php